# Compare two binary vector

Tags: c#, arrays, vector, bitarray

I have two bitarrays with each length of 200.000. I need to find how many 1's in each list at the same order. Let me draw it:

```
1   0
**1 1**
0   0
0   1
0   0
**1 1**
1   0
0   1
..  ..
```

So the result should be 2.

and I'm doing this comparison in -two nested for- about  20 million times :).

I'm doing it now with bitarray with & operator than using a popCount method to find the result.

So what do you suggest for this kind of problem. Where would you store these vectors and how would you compare them in a way that I want? I need speed.

**UPDATE:**
i ve done this with 760 lenght arrays and it took under 5 seconds with my method. Every method suggested in the comments took >1min (i stopped the program than)
So i guess its me who has to answer it. I simplified my code.

```
      for(i<761)
   var vector1 = matris[getvectorthing];
          for(j=i+1<761)
        {
   var vector2 = matris[getvectorthing];
            var similarityResult = vector1Temp.And(vector2);
            var similarityValuePay = popCount(similarityResult);
    //similarityValuePay  is result that i want
        }
    }

         private static int popCount(BitArray simRes)
            {
                Int32[] ints = new Int32[(simRes.Count >> 5) + 1];
                simRes.CopyTo(ints, 0);
                Int32 count = 0;
                // fix for not truncated bits in last integer that may have been set to true with SetAll()
                ints[ints.Length - 1] &= ~(-1 << (simRes.Count % 32));

                var tempInt = ints.Where(k => k != 0).ToArray();

                for (Int32 i = 0; i < tempInt.Length; i++)
                {
                    Int32 c = tempInt[i];
                    // magic (http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel)
                    unchecked
                    {
                        c = c - ((c >> 1) & 0x55555555);
                        c = (c & 0x33333333) + ((c >> 2) & 0x33333333);
                        c = ((c + (c >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
                    }
                    count += c;
                }
                return count;
            }
```

i asked it because may be there is much cleaver method or simple tuning to make performance better. For example:

```
var tempInt = ints.Where(k => k != 0).ToArray();
```

this ToArray() seems to be a part that i need to fix. etc.

Comment: Write some code and show us.

Comment: *" -two nested for- "* - why did you require it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `And` Method, and count `true`, I think this is faster than other answer.

```
var bit1 = new BitArray(new bool[]{true, false, ...});
var bit2 = new BitArray(new bool[]{false, false, ...});
var and = bit1.And(bit2);

var result = 0; //Total count I think you want.
for (int i = 0; i < and.Length; i++)
{
    if (and[i])
    {
        result++;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I came up with a solution for performance improvement.

Replace `popCount` to this:

```
private static int popCount(BitArray simRes)
{
    Int32[] ints = new Int32[(simRes.Count >> 5) + 1];
    simRes.CopyTo(ints, 0);
    Int32 count = 0;
    // fix for not truncated bits in last integer that may have been set to true with SetAll()
    ints[ints.Length - 1] &= ~(-1 << (simRes.Count % 32));

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
    {
        Int32 c = ints[i];
        if (c == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        // magic (http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel)
        unchecked
        {
            c = c - ((c >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            c = (c & 0x33333333) + ((c >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            c = ((c + (c >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
        }
        count += c;
    }
    return count;
}
```

In my machine, when `simRes.Length > 16000000`, `if(c == 0){...}` block gives good performance. But when `simRes.Length < 16000000`, `if(c == 0){...}` block should be deleted.

Comment: i already have huge loops and this is the first thing comes in a mind. Can u look again my update?

Comment: oh.. your popCount is much faster than my answer

Comment: i see you deleted the line     var tempInt = ints.Where(k => k != 0).ToArray(); i ve done this today :) thanks anyway

Comment: I appreciate @deyu s work but actually this is my solution. But nvm i mark it as accepted just to tell again this is the  best answer so far that we got.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this by using the `And()` method

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(new bool[] { true, true, false, false, false, true, true, false });
BitArray ba2 = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true });

int result = ba.And(ba2).Cast<bool>().Count(x => x); //2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` and `b` have equal `Length`.

```
int[] a = new[] {1,0,1, ...};
int[] b = new[] {0,0,1, ...};
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    c += a[i] == 1 && b[i] == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

Simple. Time complexity is *O(n)* where *n* is a number of elements in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise answer:

```
        bool[] A = ...;
        bool[] B = ...;


        var result = A.Where((val, ix)=>val && B[ix]).Count();
```

Comment: its an inafficent way comparing to And operator.  Can u look again my update? I tried this btw took 10x seconds than my method than i stopped it

Answer (score -2):

```
static void Main()
{
        var a = new BitArray(new bool[]{true, false,true});
        var b = new BitArray(new bool[]{false, false,true});
        int result = 0;
        int size = Math.Min( a.Length, b.Length); //or a.Length or 200000
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
        {
           if (a[i] == true && b[i] == true )
           {
              result++;
           }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",result);
}
```

Comment: WTF? why should I and some other answers get down vote? The complexity is O(n) and for sure it's not more than having an AND operation beside an O(n) iteration!

Comment: because what i said in the question that did is way better than the suggested methods and they are the first things that may come to someones mind in the first place

Comment: @KemalCanKara You updated your question after my answer!
Besides, you have no idea that doing an AND between to arrays and counting the 1s at last, is no way more efficient than what me and others have suggested you to do